# How do I log only errors and warnings from FFplay.exe?

Tags: windows

I am having trouble with FFPlay hanging up sporadically when streaming a radio station. I would like to log any warnings or errors it encounters to see if there is anything I can do to correct this. Using the command line option `-report` works, except (as is noted in the documentation) it defaults to the debug (48) level, which includes a no-stop stream of data. Using `-loglevel` warning in conjunction with `-report` doesn't work -- the level remains at 48.

The documentation says that loglevel output goes to stderr, and that appears to be true -- I can use `CreatePipe()` to capture stderr as long as the level is set to info (32) or higher, but if the level is set to warning or lower, I am unable to read `stderr` unless a warning/error has been reported, so the parent program that launched ffplay hangs when the buffer is empty. I tried using `WaitForSingleObject(pipereadhandle,0)`, to call `ReadFile()` only when there is something to read, but it always comes back signaled.

My preference would be to have ffplay log just the warnings and errors, but cannot seem to get it to write to a file without `-report`, which overrides the level specified. Alternatively, the problem would be solved if I could read the stderr buffer only when there was something there. Any thoughts?

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: My. Free scripting site? No, I was looking for people who might be able to explain why ffplay doesn't appear to behave as documented. I thought I explained a number of approaches I took (on my own, you know, trying to help myself). And I'll understand if you don't have anything constructive to offer in response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can log errors Unix style with ffplay

```
ffplay your_file.mp4 2> error_log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I have tried that, and from a command prompt it appears to work (I haven't waited long enough for an error to occur, so I cannot be sure). However, I am launching ffplay.exe from within a Win32 program that calls CreateProcess(), and if I append the redirect command (> error_log.txt) to the command line, CreateProcess() fails. I need to use CreateProcess() in order to have a process handle that I can then use to terminate ffplay later. I may be able to get around ReadFile() blocking by using a separate thread to read the pipe attached to ffplay's stdError.